# Please explain the relation between Decrease-Key and Extract-Min operations in priority queues

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, priority-queue, minimum-spanning-tree, prims-algorithm

What is the relation between `EXTRACT-MIN` operation and `DECREASE-KEY` operations in priority queue? I encountered this in the lecture for minimum spanning problem using Prim's algorithm.

The professor from MIT [refers to it at point 01:07:16 seconds in the video](http://videolectures.net/mit6046jf05_leiserson_lec16/) but I am not getting it. Can some one please clear this up for me?

P.S: I feel comfortable with my understanding of Priority Queues otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sequence:

```
DECREASE-KEY(node, -infinity)
EXTRACT-MIN
```

Has a simple meaning:

```
DELETE-KEY(node)
```

What it basically does is to make sure a certain node gets to the top of the queue and then removes it.

In Prim's algorithm, `DECREASE-KEY` is used to update the weight of nodes not yet included in the tree. As a result, a node that was thought to be too far may now move closer to the top of the queue (and therefore would be `EXTRACT-MIN`ed sooner).

I can't view the video right now, but my guess is that what your professor meant is that `DECREASE-KEY` increases the chances of a node to be `EXTRACT-MIN`ed and is in fact used for the same reason, and hence a sort of relationship.

Comment: I think the signature of Decrease-Key is Decrease-Key(x, key) and not just DECREASE-KEY(k) meaning that you change the key of item x in the heap to key. key must not be greater than x’s current key value.

Comment: Note: I can't see the video right now. If you can quote the relevant part of the speech, it would be better.

Comment: he basically says that there is an implicit relation between the two

Comment: If that's all he says, then this is all I have to say. Nevertheless, I'll be home in a couple hours and will check the video.

Comment: @geek, I heard an "implicit" around 1:10:16 (instead of 1:07:16) which doesn't seem to be that important. He is saying that depending on how you implement the priority queue, updating the value of nearby vertices _comes with an implicit DECREASE-KEY_ and that you can't just change the value without touching the data structure of the priority queue.